# Creating random text scrolling UITextView for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to create a random text scrolling UITextView for an iPhone application much like the one seen in the matrix films (http://shell-and-desktop.softlandmark.com/images/screenshots/what_is_the_matrix_screensaver-141908.jpg)

Can anyone shed any light on how to achieve the desired effect?

Thanks

Comment: UITextView is not the way to go for this. Why not just create UILabels offscreen, rotate them vertically, and animate them across some view?

Comment: It helps if you show us what you've tried already and why it's not working. Right now it seems like you're asking someone to write your program for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, nothing will save you from learning iOS SDK. You should either use it or another program built with something Eddie suggested.. like Unity...

You'll need a solid understanding of Quartz and View Animations and/or the Core Foundation Layer animations. After that, you get to decide whether you want a UILabel or UITextView, and the pros of each. You'll want enough code to understand how to use Unichar (16 bit) and/or just images of Japanese Characters.

Absolute simplest: Learn Unity and get something going that way.

Gamedev.net has some nice materials to help.

Patrick's suggestion would give you sideways Kanji, but there's ways to undo it... but you have to understand the graphics system.

UILabel + sizeToFit  + random Kanji generation + view animations or animation-ticking like games.

Just takes some time and effort.